# What is the best way to design a graphql schema around objects with similar types?

Tags: graphql

I have a similar question to this: [schema design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388837/schema-design) except for a graphql schema. I'm hoping someone who has some experience implementing graphql might be able to help me weigh the pros and cons of the below approaches.

Say I have 2 similar business objects, sedan and pickup, that have the following properties.

**Sedan**

- make
- model
- weight
- price

**Pickup**

- make
- model
- weight
- price
- bed_length
- towing capacity

does it make more sense to make a generic type called **Vehicle** and give it all the properties even though some of the types don't apply to sedans?

```
type Vehicle {
    make
    model
    weight
    price
    bed_length
    towing_capacity
}
```

or would it be better to break each out into it's own distinct type liks so:

```
type Sedan {
    make
    model
    weight
    price
}
type Pickup {
    make
    model
    weight
    price
    bed_length
    towing_capacity
}
```

or is there some better way of handling these similar objects that just have a few properties that are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define a generic type `Vehicle` but ***I would suggest only with common properties instead of cramping all the properties into base model - which is a bad approach to design a class.*** What will you do if there were more concrete types (or added in future) e.g. Sedan, Pickup, Truck, SUV so on.. will you be adding all the fields in this base Vehicle object? This might cause you problems later.

Best approach would be to use [**Interface Type**](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) where you can define a Base Interface Type with all the common fields/properties and which can be implemented by other concrete GraphQL Type.

Let me explain you with example:

Define a base/iterface type **Vehicle** as:

```
interface Vehicle {
    make: String
    model: String
    weight: String
    price: Int
}
```

Now, define concrete type **Sedan** and **Pickup** that implements **Vehicle** interface along with its *own non-common properties* as:

```
type Sedan implements Vehicle {
    make: String
    model: String
    weight: String
    price: Int
    other_info: String
}

type Pickup implements Vehicle {
    make: String
    model: String
    weight: String
    price: Int
    bed_length: Int
    towing_capacity: Int
}
```

Defining your **object types** this way provides with much more flexibility on data field projection. That means, when querying this object type, you have the flexibility to query on the common fields that present in `Vehicle` along with other fields belongs to child object type (which implements `Vehicle` type) using [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments).

```
query VehiclesList {
  vehicles {
    make
    model
    weight
    price
    ... on Sedan {
       other_info
   }
    ... on Pickup {
      bed_length
      towing_capacity
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I was looking for.